# Fast fourier coefficients for a long sum

Tags: replacement, symbolic, fourier-analysis

I have a very long expression involving a sum of exponentials, say:

```
Sum[(RandomReal[] + RandomReal[] a) Exp[2 I ii x Pi], {ii, -10, 10}]
```

I want the fastest way to get the list of Fourier coefficients. The Naive ways are pretty time-consuming:

```
Table[FourierCoefficient[f, x, ii], {ii, -10, 10}]; // Timing (*3.49906 *)
Table[1/(2 Pi) Integrate[f Exp[-ii I x], {x, -Pi, Pi}], {ii, -10, 
    10}]; // Timing (*7.3649*)
```

Is there a way to make it faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form of [`Coefficient`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Coefficient.html) would do, but requires a special case for `ii=0`:

```
fcoeff[a_, 0] := a /. E^(_. x) -> 0;
fcoeff[a_, ii_] := Coefficient[a, Exp[2 I ii x Pi]]
```

Assemble your expression (a bit abbreviated here):

```
X = Sum[(RandomReal[] + RandomReal[] a) Exp[2 I ii x Pi], {ii, -2, 2}]
(*    0.0403894 + 0.340659 a +
      (0.818202 + 0.041396 a) E^(-2 I π x) +
      (0.676596 + 0.0681271 a) E^(2 I π x) +
      (0.446339 + 0.169486 a) E^(-4 I π x) +
      (0.67812 + 0.549347 a) E^(4 I π x)        *)
```

Extract the Fourier coefficients:

```
Table[fcoeff[X, ii], {ii, -2, 2}]
(*    {0.446339 + 0.169486 a,
       0.818202 + 0.041396 a,
       0.0403894 + 0.340659 a,
       0.676596 + 0.0681271 a,
       0.67812 + 0.549347 a}      *)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want but assuming f is the function you define then

```
ClearAll[f];
f = Sum[(RandomReal[] + RandomReal[] a) Exp[2 I ii x Pi], {ii, -10, 
    10}];
ExpToTrig[f] // Simplify
```

Gives a nice list of Cos and Sin functions. Is this along the correct lines? Are the coefficients of the Cos and Sin what you need?

[image: in terms of cos and sin]